# How to call my method in mainWindow for linearGradientBrush?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, lineargradientbrush

I have a problem.

I would like to call my method in xaml (mainWindow) in `LinearGradientBrush` --> `GradientStop`

So I would like to change color in background for an animation. I have a function which has several parameters as :

```
public static List<Color> GetGradientColors(Color start, Color end, int steps)
{
    return GetGradientColors(start, end, steps, 0, steps - 1);
}

public static List<Color> GetGradientColors(Color start, Color end, int steps, int firstStep, int lastStep)
{
    var colorList = new List<Color>();
    if (steps <= 0 || firstStep < 0 || lastStep > steps - 1)
        return colorList;

    double aStep = (end.A - start.A) / steps;
    double rStep = (end.R - start.R) / steps;
    double gStep = (end.G - start.G) / steps;
    double bStep = (end.B - start.B) / steps;

    for (int i = firstStep; i < lastStep; i++)
    {
        byte a = (byte)(start.A + (int)(aStep * i));
        byte r = (byte)(start.R + (int)(rStep * i));
        byte g = (byte)(start.G + (int)(gStep * i));
        byte b = (byte)(start.B + (int)(bStep * i));
        colorList.Add(Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b));
    }

    return colorList;
}
```

In code XAML :

```
<LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.0, 0.6" EndPoint="1.0, 0.6">
    <GradientStop Color="{ Binding GetGradientColors(green, yellow, 2)}" Offset="0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? The gradient brush interpolates on its own, you just need one stop for `Green` and one for `Yellow`.

Answer (score 0):

First declare a property of type `ObservableCollection<Color>`, lets say named `Colours`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Color> Colours { get; set; }
```

Then set the property in your constructor:

```
Colours = GetGradientColors(Colors.Green, Colors.Yellow, 2);
```

Then data bind to it in XAML:

It's not exactly what you wanted, but it's about as close as you're going to get.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) that can be used [in the binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) and pass all the arguments needed as [`Binding.ConverterParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converterparameter.aspx).

Alternatively, as this does not require a "binding" anyway, you could implement a [markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.markupextension.aspx), that takes the arguments as constructor parameters:

```
<GradientStop Color="{me:GradientColor Green, Yellow, 2}" Offset="0"/>
```

Comment: Please Would you tell me how to call your GetGradientColors() function in GradientStop ? I can't call this. And thanks for reply.

Comment: @DeveloperTech2013: Read the documentation i linked to for the respective methods, should contain all the info you need.